# How to access protected method of abstract class?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Is there any way to access protected method of abstract class?

In selenium webdriver i am unable to access protected method of class "SingleBrowserLocator"

```
http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html
```

Comment: Can you subclass it ?

Comment: A `protected` member can **only** be accessed by classes in the same packages or subclasses. Maybe read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html). (Obviously you can access it with reflection, but that's another kettle of fish).

Comment: Try to extend the class to a sub class

Comment: I want to call protected method?
I have extends this abstract class "SingleBrowserLocator" but protected method is not visible.

Comment: 1) class Browser extends SingleBrowserLocator

2) public void browserTest(){
   Browser obj = new Browser();

object not display protected method.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways:

- Create a new class that extends that abstract class SingleBrowserLocator (you will have to implement the abstract methods in it);
- Search for a non abstract subclass of SingleBrowserLocator that makes that method public or has other public methods that calls the protected one;
- Search for another class in the same package of a non abstract subclass of SingleBrowserLocator that provides access to that method;

If the method is useful to you and made protected in an abstract class, probably the better or only correct choice is that you will have to implement a new subclass of it (the first choice above).

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
public abstract class Foo {
    protected void method() { ... }
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
    public void method() {
        super.method();
    }
}
```

If you can't create a subclass (named as above, or anonymous), then reflection (or something that uses it) is your best option.

Comment: public method() {
        super.method();
    }

It display an error message for "public method()"

Comment: Fixed it ... I forgot the return type.